# OpenCV: RNG generates the same numbers

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using `OpenCV` and I use `cv::RNG` to generate pick randomly a percent from the images in the list:

```
void chooseImages(const StringVector& imagesListIn, StringVector& imagesListPartOut)
{
  imagesListPartOut.clear();

  if (m_perecent == 1)
  {
    imagesListPartOut = imagesListIn;
  }
  else
  {
    // copy the imagesListIn for being able to remove the chosed images
    int percent = static_cast<int>(m_perecent * imagesListIn.size() + .5);

    cv::RNG randomChooser;
    StringVector listCpy = imagesListIn;
    int index;
    int listSize = imagesListIn.size();
    std::string name;

    for (int i = 0; i < percent; i++)
    {
      index = randomChooser.next() % listSize;
      std::cout << index << " ";
      name = listCpy[index];
      listCpy.erase(listCpy.begin() + index);
      imagesListPartOut.push_back(name);
      listSize = listCpy.size();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

My problem is that it always pick the same images; it always prints the same numbers (`cv::RNG` always generate the same numbers). How to make it generate different randomly umbers?

Comment: cv::RNG randomChooser(cv::getTickCount()); // seeed it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to seed a random number generator with a random starting state. See [rng docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#RNG). Typically you use the computer's current time

Comment: Yes, I have not thought of current time, even if I was seeding it (fixed value), it was returning same values

Comment: If you seed it with the same value it produces the same sequence. This is important, otherwise you could never test code that used a RNG.